# Rails 4: routing for has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, has-many-through, nested-resources

I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

When I simply use the following routes:

```
resources :users
resources :administrations
resources :calendars
```

everything works, meaning that I can visit

- `http://localhost:3000/users`
- `http://localhost:3000/administrations`
- `http://localhost:3000/calendars`

and CRUD instances of each model.

But this is not what I want to achieve.

What I want is to allow users to:

- Access a list of all their calendars at: `http://localhost:3000/users/:id/calendars`
- Access each of their calendar at `http://localhost:3000/users/:id/calendars/:id`
- For a given calendar, access a list of all the users of this calendar (but here I am not sure which URL would make sense).

So I figured I needed to update my routes.

Here is what I have tried:

**SOLUTION 1**

```
resources :users do
  resources :administrations
  resources :calendars
end
```

But then, when I visit `http://localhost:3000/users/1/calendars`, I get the following error:

```
NameError in Calendars#index

Showing /Users/TXC/code/rails/calendy/app/views/calendars/index.html.erb where line #27 raised:

undefined local variable or method `new_calendar_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb807e672d0>:0x007fb807e66510>

Extracted source (around line #27):

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Calendar', new_calendar_path %>
```

**SOLUTION 2**

```
concern :administratable do
  resources :administrations
end

resources :users, concerns: :administratable
resources :calendars, concerns: :administratable
```

But then, when I visit `http://localhost:3000/users/1/calendars`, I get the following error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/users/1/calendars"
```

I must be missing something obvious — sorry, I am not very experienced with Rails — but I cannot figure out why.

Any idea how I should nest my resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution 1 is the way I would take. The problem is that when you nest the resources, it causes the helpers to change (you can see this by running `rake routes`). The correct helper method is `new_user_calendar_path` so change

```
<%= link_to 'New Calendar', new_calendar_path %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to 'New Calendar', new_user_calendar_path(@user) %>
```

where *@user* is set in the controller to point to correct user.

**Bonus**

You could also take a look at the [shallow routes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) (section 2.7.2 in that page). They provide a cleaner way to call the nested calendars with URL

```
GET /calendars/:id
```

instead of

```
GET /users/:userId/calendars/:calendarId
```

since the *calendarId* is anyway unique.

Comment: Yes. this is what the answer is.